# Develop Printer Driver which can Read file and Write extra data

Tags: printing, driver, wdk, v4-printer-driver

I need to develop a **printer driver** which can:-

1. **Read** the printed file (knowing the data inside the file)
2. **Write** extra information to the end of printed file. (eg. bar-code or QR code)

I plan to use **V4 printer driver** as template for me to start my development. I already tried to built this V4 printer driver in Visual Studio.

[*V4 printer driver solution explorer*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwGN6.png)

Understanding the *architecture of V4 printer driver* may need lot of times. Besides that, I am still new in driver development, so it is hard for me to understand the document provided by Microsoft.

Can anyone suggest where should I start to code and recommend me any useful method/function or library. It will be useful if anyone can recommend some useful related reading material and what basic knowledge should I know.

Answer (score 1):

See the Microsoft sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/print-an-xps-om#incrementally-print-an-xps-om).

Create a "Render Filter" project (C++ project) in your "V4 Printer Driver" solution and add the sample code in "StartOperation_throws" method of newly created Render Filter.

Then use following sample code to add a custom content to your file:

```
XPS_COLOR testColor;

testColor.value.sRGB.alpha=0xFF;
testColor.value.sRGB.red=0xFF;
testColor.value.sRGB.green=0xFF;
testColor.value.sRGB.blue=0xFF;
testColor.colorType = XPS_COLOR_TYPE_SRGB;

FLOAT Font_Size = 14;
XPS_POINT OrgPoint = {123,123};
LPCWSTR TestStr = _T("Sample Text");
LPCWSTR Name_fnt = _T("SampleFontFile.TTF");
```

at the end, call "AddCustomTextToXpsDoc" using above parameters to add your text in
printable xps file.